# OPENEDGE (ODBC) Joining without Duplicates on ID

Tags: sql, openedge

trying to query 3 tables without duplicates on the `Object_ID`

If this is not possible, order for both `Object_ID`, so the duplicates of **both** `Object_ID`s are among themselves, would also do the trick for me. But this is not really working for me, since Im only able to `order by` one `Object_ID`, so the duplicates are among themselves.

Tables:

S_Anl

```
Ktr         Anl
4711        1234
4711        5678
4711        9000
```

AB_Erg

```
Anl    AB_Erg_Obj     Value
1234   c9d91f         1000
1234   696bfc         2000
1234   8c9915         3000
5678   141a65         4000
```

E_BP

```
Anl   E_BP_Obj      Value
1234  99f75ab       500
1234  720e573       100
9000  830614c       50
9000  958ac28       200
```

Query

```
SELECT B.AB_Erg_Obj, C.E_BP_Obj, A.Anl, B.Value, C.Value
FROM PUB.S_Anl AS A 
LEFT JOIN PUB.AB_Erg AS B ON A.Anl = B.Anl
LEFT JOIN PUB.E_BP AS C ON A.Anl = C.Anl
WHERE A.Ktr = '4711'
ORDER BY A.Anl, B.AB_Erg_Obj, C.E_BP_Obj
with (nolock)
```

Expected Result

```
Anl  AB_Erg_Obj   E_BP_Obj   Value  Value
1234 c9d91f       99f75ab    1000   500
1234 696bfc       720e573    2000   100
1234 8c9915       NULL       3000   NULL
5678 141a65       NULL       4000   NULL
9000 830614c      830614c    NULL   50
9000 958ac28      958ac28    NULL   200
```

Or Ordering `AB_Erg_Obj` and `E_BP_Obj` among themselves.
Is either of this possible?

**//EDIT:**

I know that ordering wouldnt remove duplicates in the result set, but it would be easier to do it afterwards.

Also its not necassary that the data is matched exactly on row-level, I just need the overall sum of Value from E_BP and Value of AB_Erg in the first place - because of that exact matching on row-level is not needed, just no duplicates on the Object_ID-Level

Comment: I know that ordering wouldnt remove duplicates in the result set, but it would be easier to do it afterwards. Also its not necassary that the data is matched exactly, i just need the overall sum of Value from E_BP and Value of AB_Erg in the first place - because of that exact matching on row-level is not needed, just no duplicates

Comment: I might be missing something here, but I believe the expected result wouldn't be reached because 696bfc would alphabetically come before c9d91f. I managed to create a calculated field concatenating ab_erg_obj and e_bp_obj and adding an order by that, but my result isn't exactly what you had there.